# Where should optional <div>s be stored in html?

Tags: jquery, html

I have an html page where quite a few overlays have to be displayed.  All these overlays have been enclosed by  tags.  Since the html becomes very big if I choose to store all the s in the main page, can I store these  snippets as separate files?  If so, how do I bring them into, as required.  Currently jQuery is being used to hide / show these snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you concerned with your HTML being 'big' because you want to have your pages load faster or because it becomes too much code to work through?

If it's the first reason, then instead of showing and hiding the DIVs with jQuery, dynamically create and destroy the DIVs with jQuery only when you need them. (Though, unless it's a ton of DIVs, I can't see you saving much in terms of the size of your page.)

If it's the second reason, then if you're using a dynamic language of some sort (php, ruby, etc.) put them in separate file and include them OR get a text editor that supports code folding so you can get them out of your way when you're writing your code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can serve each of the snippets independently, and use JavaScript Ajax requests to get them from the server and insert them into the DOM.

Search for Ajax tutorial, ideally in whatever framework you're using.